# Flink with Kafka source and Iceberg sink doesn't write

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql, apache-iceberg

Using Flink I am trying to read data from Kafka, convert the Protobuf event to a Json string and write it to a table in Iceberg.

I've written the code by following the official docs, but I must have missed something.
The job successfully connects to Kafka, and I can see it producing logs and parsing events, but it never writes to disk.
It does however connect to Iceberg, and it seems to make an empty table.
[image]
What am I missing, why is the sink never actually being triggered?

```java
public class App {


    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        // Check if the S3 endpoint IP argument is provided
        if (args.length < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Please provide the S3 endpoint IP as an argument");
        }
        String s3EndpointIp = args[0];

        LOG.info("JOB Env setup");

        // Set up the Flink environment
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        env.setParallelism(1);
        final StreamTableEnvironment tableEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(
                env,
                EnvironmentSettings.newInstance().inStreamingMode().build());

        // create the Nessie catalog
        tableEnv.executeSql(
                String.format(
                        "CREATE CATALOG iceberg WITH ("
                                + "'type'='iceberg',"
                                + "'catalog-impl'='org.apache.iceberg.nessie.NessieCatalog',"
                                + "'io-impl'='org.apache.iceberg.aws.s3.S3FileIO',"
                                + "'uri'='http://catalog:19120/api/v1',"
                                + "'authentication.type'='none',"
                                + "'ref'='main',"
                                + "'client.assume-role.region'='local',"
                                + "'warehouse' = 's3://warehouse',"
                                + "'s3.endpoint'='http://%s:9000'"
                                + ")",
                        s3EndpointIp));

        // Set the current catalog to the new catalog
        tableEnv.useCatalog("iceberg");

        // Create a database in the current catalog
        tableEnv.executeSql("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS db");

        // create the table
        tableEnv.executeSql(
                "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db.table1 ("
                        + "data STRING"
                        + ")");

        LOG.info("JOB Kafka setup");

        KafkaSourceBuilder<String> kafkaSourceBuilder = KafkaSource
                .<String>builder()
                .setProperty("security.protocol", "SASL_SSL")
                .setProperty("sasl.mechanism", "SCRAM-SHA-256")
                .setProperty("ssl.truststore.location", "./jks/truststore.jks")
                .setProperty("ssl.truststore.password", "strong-password")
                .setProperty("sasl.jaas.config",
                        "org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required " +
                                "username=\"username\" " +
                                "password=\"strong-password\";")
                .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.earliest())
                .setBootstrapServers("my-dns:my-port")
                .setGroupId("datalake-flink-java")
                .setTopics(Arrays.asList("my-kafka-topic"))
                .setDeserializer(new EventDeserializationSchema()); // missing
        KafkaSource<String> kafkaSource = kafkaSourceBuilder.build();


        DataStream<String> processedStream = env
            .fromSource(kafkaSource, WatermarkStrategy.noWatermarks(), "Kafka Source")
            .map(new MapFunction<String, String>() {
                @Override
                public String map(String value) {
                    LOG.info("Mapping value");
                    return value;
                }
            });

        FileSink<String> sink = FileSink
            .forRowFormat(new Path("db.table1"), new SimpleStringEncoder<String>("UTF-8"))
            .withRollingPolicy(
                DefaultRollingPolicy.builder()
                    .withRolloverInterval(Duration.ofMinutes(5))
                    .withInactivityInterval(Duration.ofMinutes(2))
                    .withMaxPartSize(MemorySize.ofMebiBytes(256))
                    .build())
            .build();

        processedStream.sinkTo(sink);

        env.execute("Kafka to Iceberg job");

    }


    public static class EventDeserializationSchema implements KafkaRecordDeserializationSchema<String> {

        @Override
        public void deserialize(ConsumerRecord<byte[], byte[]> record, Collector<String> collector) throws IOException {
            try {
                ResponseEnrichedEvent parsed = ResponseEnrichedEvent.parseFrom(record.value());
                LOG.info("About to deserialize Kafka record");
                String jsonString = JsonFormat.printer().print(parsed);
                collector.collect(jsonString);
                LOG.info("Successfully to deserialized Kafka record");
            } catch (InvalidProtocolBufferException e) {
                LOG.error("Failed to deserialize Kafka record", e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public TypeInformation<String> getProducedType() {
            return TypeInformation.of(String.class);
        }
    }
    
}
```

```
console

datalake-flink-taskmanager-1  | 2023-10-26 17:06:59,925 INFO  App                                              [] - Mapping value
datalake-flink-taskmanager-1  | 2023-10-26 17:06:59,925 INFO  App                                              [] - Successfully to deserialized Kafka record
datalake-flink-taskmanager-1  | 2023-10-26 17:06:59,925 INFO  App                                              [] - About to deserialize Kafka record
datalake-flink-taskmanager-1  | 2023-10-26 17:06:59,925 INFO  App                                              [] - Mapping value
datalake-flink-taskmanager-1  | 2023-10-26 17:06:59,926 INFO  App                                              [] - Successfully to deserialized Kafka record
```

I do also see that the source is created, but not the sink.

I tried to rewrite the code so that the sink is in a separate class and to only use SQL, but I seem to end up having similar results.

Comment: Not exactly sure but you can check if `processedStream` should be converted to some `java types` before writing it to the sink

Comment: Have you enabled checkpointing?

Comment: Hi @MartijnVisser, I added `env.enableCheckpointing(5000);` but all it did was create checkpointing logs to stdout, no actual data was written.

Answer (score 2):

Your code correctly creates the Iceberg table, but you are trying to write the data using `FileSink` (I assume this is `org.apache.flink.connector.file.sink.FileSink`).

If your goal is to write to the Iceberg table, you should use `org.apache.iceberg.flink.sink.FlinkSink` like mentioned here: https://iceberg.apache.org/docs/latest/flink/#writing

For example:

```
FlinkSink.forRowData(input)
.tableLoader(tableLoader)
.append();
```

Or, as you have already discovered, you can use FlinkSQL to write the data:

```
processedTable.executeInsert("db.table1");
```

Or the same with actual SQL commands:

```
INSERT INTO `hive_catalog`.`db`.`table1` SELECT id, data from other_kafka_table;
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make it work by changing my approach slightly, I added checkpointing as the comments suggested and then i used the `tableEnv` created directly via `tableEnv.fromDataStream()` for writing, instead of using a FileSink. The `tableEnv` was already configured to use Iceberg directly.

However, I do see that `tableEnv.fromDataStream` is considered deprecated for version 1.17+, so a more future proof solution could be found.

So during init I did:

```java
// Set up the Flink environment
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        env.setParallelism(1);
        env.enableCheckpointing(5000);
        final StreamTableEnvironment tableEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(
                env,
                EnvironmentSettings.newInstance().inStreamingMode().build());
```

and then instead of using FileSink I did this:

```java
        // Convert DataStream to Table
        org.apache.flink.table.api.Table processedTable = tableEnv.fromDataStream(processedStream, $("data"));


        // Write Table to Iceberg
        processedTable.executeInsert("db.table1");
```